# switch文内で変数を代入したい

Tags: objective-c

自分なりにいろいろ調べてみたのですがどうしても分からないので質問させていただきます。
XCode 5.0 です

```c
-(void)tick:(NSTimer *) theTimer  {

    switch (segment.selectedSegmentIndex){
        case 0:
            [self countTimeup=kTimeup];
            break;

        case 1:
            [self countTimeup=hTimeup];
            break;

        case 2:
            [self countTimeup=eTimeup];
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }        
}
```

エラーが出るのは三カ所の `[self countTimeup~];` で
`Expected']'` のエラーが出ます。
SegmentedControlのボタンによってcountTimeupに違う値を代入したいです。
質問の意図が分かりにくかったら申し訳ないです、どうかお助けください。

**追記分**

ありがとうございます以下がエラーメッセージになります。

```
[self setcountTimeup:kTimeup];
No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'setcountTimeup:'
 self.countTimeup=kTimeup;
Property 'countTimeup' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'; did you mean to access instance variable 'countTimeup'?
countTimeup=kTimeup;
Assigning to 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *') from incompatible type 'float'
```

念のためすべてのパターンを書いておきました。

**再追記分**

Onodaさん見にくいのでこちらに書きました、ご確認お願いします。

```
#define kTimeup (2.0f/kTimerMoleInterval)

#define hTimeup (1.0f/hTimerMoleInterval)

#define eTimeup (0.5f/eTimerMoleInterval)

#define kTimerMoleInterval 1.0f
#define hTimerMoleInterval 0.5f
#define eTimerMoleInterval 0.3f
```

`countTimeup` は `.m` 内の

```
@implementation ViewController{}
NSInteger *countTimeup;
```

このように記述しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

countTimeup と kTimeup/hTimeup/eTimeup の定義はどこに、どのように記述してるでしょうか？

これが分からないことには正解を答えることはできませんが、エラーから察するにクラスに属する変数ではなさそうなので、変数の型を合わせて↓のスタイルで代入してみてください。

```
countTimeup=kTimeup;
```

Comment: Onodaさん回答ありがとうございます。
まずcountTimeupですが.m内の@implementation ViewController{}
に定義しています。
k.h.e/Timeupはすべてヘッダにマクロとして記述しています。
回答してくださったお二方には申し訳ないです、質問の書き方が悪かったです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。それぞれ、どう記述してるか書いていただけると助かります。たとえば、
   float countTimeup;
とか。

Comment: 代入しようとしてる変数の型が違うからエラーが出てるので、float countTimeup; とするか、どうしても NSInteger *型である必要があるのでしたら代入する値の方を型に合わせる必要があります。

Answer (score 3):

countTimeupがプロパティであれば

```
[self setCountTimeup:kTimeup];
```

または

```
self.countTimeup=kTimeup;
```

だと思われます。

変数であれば

```
countTimeup=kTimeup;
```

です。

エラーの内容からすると、kTimeupはポインタ型のようですので`*kTimeup`としてください。

Comment: pgrhoさん回答ありがとうございます、早速ためさせていただきましたが、また別のエラーになってしまいました。

Comment: プロパティではないようなので回答を編集しました。上記でもエラーが発生するようならちょっと原因が思いつかないので、エラーメッセージを転載してください。

Comment: countTimeup=*kTimeup;
何度も申し訳ありません、＊の場所はここで良いでしょうか？
この場所に入れたところまたエラーメッセージがでてしまいました。

Indirection requires pointer operand ('float' invalid)

Answer (score 1):

まず、NSIntegerとは、名前が意味するようなオブジェクトではなくて、実際には、

typedef long int NSInteger;

と定義されてます。これは、Xcodeのクラスリファレンスの引き方を知っている人なら、two clicksで、ドキュメントをだせる。

だから、あなたのやっているのは、

long int *countTimeup;

countTimeup = float_value;

ということで、Cの意味でも全然、間違いなわけです。なぜなら、左辺は、アドレス値を要求しているわけだし、
右辺は、floatの値だから。

正しくは、

float countTimeup;

と宣言して、それに計算式を代入する。

countTimeup= xxxxxx;